# Python Compare 2 CSVs - Averaging 2 Column

Tags: python

I want to get the average of the a column in the 2 csv files

```
import csv

master = open('master.csv', 'r')
export = open('export.csv', 'r')

#output
outFile = open ('out.csv', 'w')
csvWriter = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',')

# Process input files
csv1 = csv.reader(master, delimiter=',')
csv2 = csv.reader(export, delimiter=',')

# Skip headers
next(csv1)
next(csv2)

for rowExport in csv2:
    # Get each line in MasterList
    rowMaster = next(csv1)

    #output line from Export values
    colA = str(rowMaster[1])
    colB = str(rowExport[5])

    #Average colB is the average of 2 same column in master and export (in master it is in column 2 while column 5 in export)
    if float(rowExport[5])*2 > float(rowMaster[2]):
        colB = str((float(rowExport[5])+float(rowMaster[2])/2))    
    csvWriter.writerow([colA, colB])                                                                                     

master.close()
export.close()
outFile.close()
```

I only want to get the average of the Docs Queued Column Based on the Client IDs in the Master CSV.  See attached images.

[Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fegnC.png)
[Master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVemQ.png)

What i am getting is that it put the average based on row, it doesn't match it with the Client ID. Since it is randomly sorted
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtrTf.png)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: sorry, whenever i put it in the code block it says add 4 space but it is already in the code block, ill try to fix this